# UWP Command run every time instead of onclick event

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

I have a login page.

After the user logs in it will redirect to a page which contains a text box for the selected city. When clicking it, it will show a list of cities.

I have written the onclick event using a command in uwp. It calls every time after login success. I don't know why this has happened?

I have written it only for onclick event:

```
<TextBlock Text="community" x:Uid="SelectCommunity"  FontSize="15" Foreground="Black" TextAlignment="Left"   Margin="10,8,38,70"  Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.RowSpan="2" />
                                    <TextBlock Text="*" Foreground="Red" Grid.Column="1" TextAlignment="Right" Margin="0,10,38,70" Grid.RowSpan="2"/>
                                    <TextBox Visibility="Collapsed"   Text="{Binding _common[0].Community_Name}" Background="Yellow" BorderBrush="#c0c0c0" Foreground="Black"  Name="txtcommunity"  FontSize="15" Margin="0,10.333,34,0"  Grid.Row="1">
                                    </TextBox>
                                    <TextBox   Text="{Binding _common[0].Community_Name,Mode=TwoWay}"  IsReadOnly="True"  Background="Yellow" BorderBrush="#c0c0c0" Foreground="Black"  FontSize="13"  Margin="10,10.333,38,25"  Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
                                        <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                                            <Core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="GotFocus">
                                                <Core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding DataContext.CommunityCmd,ElementName=Sectors,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=txtcommunity}" ></Core:InvokeCommandAction>
                                            </Core:EventTriggerBehavior>
                                        </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                                    </TextBox>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are handling the `GotFocus` event (

```
<Core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="GotFocus" ..>
```

) which means that you command will be invoked each time the `TextBox` is focused. You may try to handle another event such as for example `PointerEntered` or `Tapped`.

Comment: GotFocus means  only one textbox getting focused at a time actually in my code all the commands has hitted when that page become loaded. I have add another button with EventName Tapped but that has been also hitted. I don't know why this happened ?

Comment: Maybe there's something else you haven't explained. Please provide a [mcve].